# T-SQL for autogrowth of multiple data files

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, tsql

I can't seem to figure out the problems with my script to alter SQL Server 2008 database and file growth. There are two data files and a log file, all which need to have Autogrowth ON. Does this look completely wrong? Thanks!

```
USE MASTER
GO
ALTER DATABASE BigDB
MODIFY FILE
( NAME = BIGDBPPE,
FILENAME = "H:\MSSQL\Data\BigDB.mdf",
MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED,
FILEGROWTH = 2000MB)

USE MASTER
GO
ALTER DATABASE BigDB
MODIFY FILE
( NAME = BIGDBPPE1,
FILENAME = "K:\MSSQL\Data\BigDB_data1.ndf",
MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED,
FILEGROWTH = 2000MB)

USE MASTER
GO
ALTER DATABASE BigDB
MODIFY FILE
( NAME = BIGDBPPE_log,
FILENAME = "O:\MSSQL\Data\BigDB_log.ldf",
MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED,
FILEGROWTH = 200MB)
GO
```

Comment: Is it giving any sort of error?

Comment: According to SQL Server, syntax isn't correct on fourth line after 'MODIFY FILE' and sites the beginning parentheses as the error.

Comment: Is it SQL express?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 Enterprise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax looks ok, make sure the database name doesn't need to be [square-bracketed] and that the logical names match.

Comment: Not sure what the issue was, but connecting to the SQL Server from the local machine worked without issues. Thank you!